# expand looping a href inside div jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm struggling with expanding each a href inside a div tag in a loop state. i want each a href to expand and hide dynamically on click event.

Here is what I have:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $("#author_bio_wrap_toggle").click(function($)
                {
                    $("#author_bio_wrap").slideToggle( "slow");

                });
            });

<div class="divTable">  
            <div class="bs-example">    
                    <div  class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
                        <i class="fa fa-home gihombing"></i> List Template Expertisi
                    </a>
                ';
                
                while ($rr = $rh->fetchRow())
                            
                {  
                    
$html .='               
                        <a href="#"   id="author_bio_wrap_toggle" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                            <div  class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <h4>'.$rr['nmpasien'].'</h4>
                                <small>1 hari lalu </small>
                            </div>
                            <p>No MR : '.$rr['ps_mrn'].' , Tindakan : '.$rr['jnisdiit'].'</p>
                            <div id="author_bio_wrap" style="display: none;">
                            <input type="button" class="button111" id="soundOffbutton"  name="soundOffbutton" value="Isi Hasil"   style="width:100px; height:30px; " onclick="silent();" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="button" class="button111" id="soundOffbutton"  name="soundOffbutton" value="Re-Schedule"   style="width:100px; height:30px; " onclick="silent();" >
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    
        ';  

                }  

$html .='   
            </div>
```

thank you verymuch

Comment: Kindly post the full source code. including the HTML and CSS.

Comment: And please format your code, it is very, very hard to read :)